# Hbase put shell command

Tags: shell, hbase

How can I use the put command in Hbase shell to insert more than one value. I have a column family having five qualifiers. How can I insert values to all those 5 qualifiers using one single command using Put

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot do that from the HBase shell. The 'put' command is used to "[Put a cell 'value' at specified table/row/column](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell)". It's for 'putting' a single value.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why HBase does not allow multiple inserts.

Comment: I guess it tries to adhere to programming paradigm to interpret map. In, say Java map, we put single value at a time. But, I guess, here, if we want to put multiple cells in same row. we must be doing put with all: row key, column qualifier and timestamp.